# What does mean by line item in the order?

Tags: magento2, cart

While tax calculation we have an option of "Row Total" thats depend on the line items in the order.Can someone explain the term line item in the order?

Answer (score 1):

The line item in the order in the sense when we place an order with a number of items in Magento. in order level, it shows all the items as line level

please refer below link it may useful

https://support.accumula.com/hc/en-us/articles/201621094-Magento-Order-Line-Items-and-Details